# Adding Objects to NSSet

Tags: ios, objective-c, set, nsset

I have 2 objects (Object A & Object B) that point to the same NSSet.

If I delete objects from the set, both Object A & B see the deletion.

If I add an object to the set from Object A, this isn't reflected in Object B and vice versa.

If they are both pointing at the same object, why don't they see the additions because they do see the deletions.

Must be missing something simple here?

Thanks guys

Comment: Some code would be helpful. Both how you create the set, delete objects, add objects and how A and B references the set

Comment: First of all, you cant add and delete from `NSSet` which i guess in immutable.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya I just assumed the OP used an NSMutableSet

Comment: The way you formulated the question is a bit vague and ambiguous. Specifically: objects don't point to anything (variables do). It seems that you mixed up these terms. Please clarify what you mean or post your code.

Comment: are you sure they point to the exact same object? because if they do, the addition must reflect as well. I assume you add an object using the `–initWithObject:` or `–setWithObject:` method and it will create you a different `NSSet` instance, so the _ObjectA_ and _ObjectB_ won't point the same object anymore, therefore you cannot expect any reflection between them.